# Как нанести два текста подряд через imagettftext

Tags: изображения, php

```
$watertext=iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $watertext);
$watertextlogo=iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", 'sitename');

$waterlogo=imagecreate(50,25);
$water=imagecreate($width-50,25);

$cbacklogo=imagecolorallocate($waterlogo,244,244,244);
$cback=imagecolorallocate($water,244,244,244);

$textcollogo=imagecolorallocate($waterlogo,73,111,152);
$textcol=imagecolorallocate($water,132,163,196);

imageFilledRectangle($waterlogo.$water,0,0,$width-1,24,$cback);

imagettftext($waterlogo,$fontsize,0,6,$basepoint,$textcollogo,$font,$watertextlogo);
imagettftext($water,$fontsize,0,50,$basepoint,$textcol,$font,$watertext);

$newimg=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height+25);
$niback=imagecolorallocate($newimg,255,255,255);
imageFilledRectangle($newimg,0,0,$width-1,$height+24,$niback);

imagecopy($newimg,$oimg,0,0,0,0,$width,$height);
imagecopy($newimg,$waterlogo,0,$height,0,0,50,25);
imagecopy($newimg,$water,0,$height,50,0,$width-50,25);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы сначала был нанесен $waterlogo (sitename), а после за ним шел текст $water. Но почему то текст sitename не наносится, хотя текст $water наносится.

Comment: Обновил код. Но все равно не получается вставить $waterlogo, хотя $water вставляется.

Comment: Так вы ж их наносите на 2 разных изображения?..

Comment: Нет, на 1 изображение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых: включаем показ ошибок. Ну не могло у вас нормально интерпретироваться

```
imageFilledRectangle($waterlogo.$water,0,0,$width-1,24,$cback); // склейка 2 ресурсов в строку
```

Далее:

```
imagecopy($newimg,$waterlogo,0,$height,0,0,50,25);
imagecopy($newimg,$water,0,$height,50,0,$width-50,25);
```

Здесь вы накладываете изображения друг на друга и спрашиваете, почему одно из них не видно, да?) 5й параметр `src_x` - это "с какого Х копировать изначальное изображение", а 3й `dst_x` - "куда вставить в конечное изображение". Итого:

```
imagecopy($newimg,$waterlogo,0,$height,0,0,50,25);
imagecopy($newimg,$water,50,$height,0,0,$width-50,25);
```

Во всяком случае, у меня отработало нормально.

*Вообще, если честно, я не понимаю, зачем вам здесь 3 изображения и почему бы не сохранить водяной знак в отдельный файл*

Comment: Фух, спасибо, все поправил - сейчас накладывается оба изображения. Но фон прямоугольник криво, конечно, рисуется, но это исправимо.